# External Fragmentation in FreeBSD due to unmovable Kernel pages

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, freebsd, bsd, defragmentation

Is external fragmentation an issue in FreeBSD due to unmovable Kernel pages similar to what Linux [(1)](https://lwn.net/Articles/249012/) [(2)](https://lwn.net/Articles/211505/) faces?